# MKDirections failing in iOS 9 Beta

Tags: ios, iphone, beta, xcode7, ios9

I have decided to upgrade my iPhone and Xcode to the latest betas and have been hit with a hurdle.

When I execute a MKDirectionsResponse, I get the following error:

```
   PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain   
   Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the 
   server cannot be made."
```

and

```
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc,
   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x1bb58330 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be   
   made.",
```

I've tried exempting `gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com` in my `Plist`'s, `NSAppTransportSecurity` - even though it's a secure network. What should I do in order for it to work properly?

Comment: A few other tips to help debug: `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` will turn off ATS.
And the environment variable: `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS=1` will log network errors to the console.  (I haven't tried either of these yet, just gathered them from the WWDC Session on ATS.)

Comment: cheers for that @JonBrooks - will see how it pans out..

Comment: See this forum post on same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4988